# Error converting data type varchar to datetime. Need to return records based on the date or all records if no date is specified

Tags: sql-server

I have implemented a storedprocedure and basically want the storedprocedure to return all records if no parameter is sent or records based on parameter sent. I am using date as the parameter. I am getting an error when executing `exec [dbo].[getLog] '27/07/2017'` . The error is

> Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

Could somebody tell me what is incorrect in the logic

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[getLog] 
@dateFrom datetime  
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT * from [CoreAnalytics].[dbo].[Logs]
    where [TimeStamp]  > ISNULL(@dateFrom, 0)  ;
END
GO
```

Comment: what is the dataype of Logs.TimeStamp ?

Comment: its datetime datatype

Comment: so if the dateFrom variable is null than you are doing where TimeStamp > 0

Comment: I know it works for int fields. How do I handle it for datetime fields. I need to be able to send all records if date parameter is not supplied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct you want to return all records if @dateFrom is null, or filter on that variable.
I think you need something like this then

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[getLog] @dateFrom datetime  
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * from [CoreAnalytics].[dbo].[Logs]
    where (@dateFrom is null or [TimeStamp] > @dateFrom)
END
```

Make sure you are passing a valid datetime when calling the procedure.
It is best to use an universal format that will work with any database,

yyyyMMdd is a format that will always work.
http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

```
exec [dbo].[getLog] '20170727'
```

should always work

Comment: i am still getting the error Error converting data type varchar to datetime.
when executing exec [dbo].[getLog] '27/07/2017'

Comment: are you sure that this is the only code in that procedure ?

Comment: And are you sure that the field TimeStamp is of type datetime ?

Comment: The problem is that @Tom is passing `'27/07/2017'` as datatime. This is causing problem.

Comment: @Tom Instead of `'27/07/2017'` use `'2017-07-27'` and check.

Comment: I have edited my answer. The problem is how you call the procedure